# Why is there an upper bound to the frequency at which an electronic device can be operated?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity, electric-circuits

Why is there an upper bound to the frequency at which an electronic device can be operated? For example, the frequency of electricity that we receive at home is 60Hz (in the USA).

1. What will happen if we increase the frequency?
2. Is there any relation between speed of the device and its operating frequency? For example, if we are operating a sensor at 60Hz and one at 1000Hz, will there be any difference between the response time of two?

Answer (score 2):

For simple passive circuits, the upper limit to operation is the stray capacitance and inductance of the circuit elements. For example, in the AC mains system, the transformers used have sufficient inductance to choke off most signals above ~60 to 100Hz. In high-impedance microphone cable, the stray capacitance of the cable is sufficient to shunt to ground any frequencies above ~15kHz for long runs of that cable.

For complex active circuits containing transistors, the frequency response is limited by the physics inside the semiconductor: for frequencies that are too high, the depletion zones and charge transport inside the silicon cannot form and disappear fast enough to keep up with the driving signal, and they stop amplifying or otherwise processing the signal.

Signal sensors are subject to these same limitations. If you try to detect a 1000Hz signal with a sensor that limits out at 60Hz, you'll get no reading. If on the other hand if you try to sense a 60Hz signal with a sensor that limits out at 1000Hz, you will get a proper signal.

Comment: In electronic devices the frequency response is also limited by parasitic resistances and capacitances. Even effects resulting from carrier depletion and transport can be modeled as capacitances. Other parasitics include the capacitances between the device terminals (due to their proximity) and the series resistance of the (ideally highly conductive) heavily doped drain and source in transistors. All these parasitics are on top of the capacitance of the output devices being driven and the resistance of the interconnects in the signal path.

Comment: To offer the dual of the situation in your last paragraph, if you try to sense something at 1000Hz, you may find that its hard to get enough energy into the sensor to detect the signal if the signal is particularly dim.  It may be easier to get enough energy at the slower rate. (This is a major limitation in high speed cameras)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be referring to the frequency of the a.c. mains supply. This is pretty much irrelevant to the operation of most electronic devices, because inside the device the mains supply is 'processed' (transformed to a lower voltage, rectified and smoothed) to produce d.c. (a constant voltage). This is what almost all electronic circuits run on. So if a 60 Hz supply were replaced by a 1000 Hz supply of the same peak voltage it would make no difference to the functioning of the device, as long as the 'power processing' part of the device was modified to deal with 1000 Hz rather than 60 Hz.